# i made some changes in my frappe app locally. After that i accepted it from visual studio code as i have cloned it on my system

Tags: git, frappe

I made some changes in my `frappe` app locally.
After that I accepted it from Visual Studio Code as I have cloned it on my system.

After that, I opened my Linux terminal and look at the status  by **git status**, it was showing the changes I have made.

After that, I typed **git commit -m "my changes"**.
And in last, I pushed it to the main server by **git push upstream new_branch**.

But right now, I only have read permission, so I could not do it.

So my question is: when I will get write permission of the main project, will I have to do this process again?
Or can I simply push it again?
Because now when I type git status, it is showing there is nothing to commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple push will be enough.

To gain write access on a remote repository does not change your local clone and local work.

Note: one does not generally push directly to `upstream`, only to the default remote '`origin`' which should point to your own repository (or fork of a repository).

Once push, you can initiate a [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) with, as a target, a branch of the original upstream repository.

Comment: Okay. But when i push it by command in linux, in remote it is mentioned "forbidden" .

Comment: @AdityaVig That means the remote named 'upstream' has an URL refereing to a remote repository you do not own, or you are not part of the collaborators with push access. Do a `git remote -v` to show what `upstream` refers to, and to check you have a remote named 'origin' as well.